# AMD Ryzen fan constantly very loud

Tags: fan, amd-processor, sensors

i assembled a new pc for work and gave the new AMD cpu a chance (Ryzen 5 1600 - NOT 1600X). So far everything works really smooth and fast. BUT the cpu fan is constantly on a very loud level, even if the pc is idle, the fan will get very loud. It sounds like the fan is constantly running between 60 and 100% rpm (going up and down... like a sine wave).

Does anyone experience similar issues or is it more likely that i have a hardware issue?

I dont have a windows installation, so i cant tell for sure if its linux related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to fix the problem, so i decided to buy a new cooler. Most likely the fan was broken.

Comment: **This is a self-answer.** Please leave the answer intact and close the question instead!